# How to parse a fixed width text file in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing

I have a massive amount of data that looks like this:

```
 PHHI   GFSX MOS GUIDANCE  10/19/2012  1200 UTC                       
 FHR  24  36| 48  60| 72  84| 96 108|120 132|144 156|168 180|192      
      SAT 20| SUN 21| MON 22| TUE 23| WED 24| THU 25| FRI 26|SAT CLIMO
 N/X  66  80| 68  82| 66  82| 66  81| 66  80| 67  82| 67  81| 67999999
 TMP  69  79| 71  81| 69  80| 69  80| 69  79| 69  80| 70  80| 70      
 DPT  63  64| 66  63| 64  64| 65  64| 65  66| 66  68| 68  65| 66      
 WND  11  10| 10  12| 11   9|  9   8|  8   8|  8   8|  8   7|  7      
 P12   8   9| 11   9| 21  14| 20  10| 18  20| 28  28| 46  15| 32999999
 P24      14|     19|     14|     23|     19|     36|     40|      999
 Q12   0   0|  0   0|  0   0|  0   0|  0   0|  1   1|       |         
 Q24       0|      0|      0|      0|      0|      1|       |         

 PHJH   GFSX MOS GUIDANCE  10/19/2012  1200 UTC                       
 FHR  24  36| 48  60| 72  84| 96 108|120 132|144 156|168 180|192      
      SAT 20| SUN 21| MON 22| TUE 23| WED 24| THU 25| FRI 26|SAT CLIMO
 N/X 999  84|999  84|999  84|999  85|999  84|999  84|999  84|999999999
 TMP 999  83|999  82|999  83|999  83|999  83|999  83|999  83|999      
 ........etc
```

I need to process it in PHP such that it can be placed into a MYSQL database.

In the first line, the first word is needed (station's name) and the date/time is needed.
The second and third lines are not needed at all. The `|` character is irrelevant. 
The last two columns are problematic:

```
192      
SAT CLIMO
 67999999
 70      
 66      
  7      
 32999999
      999
```

The numbers are touching each other, but really they are 2 seperate variables. It should look more like this:

```
192      
SAT CLIMO
 67 999999
 70      
 66      
  7      
 32 999999
      999
```

Any tips on how I can parse this? Are there any accessory functions for parsing fixed width data?

Comment: Fixed width makes it super easy to parse, what's the problem? Just substring it.

Comment: No this ist Not already answered in the linked question! linked answered require whitespace to function this ist Not truely a fixed Format. The use of unpack() would be a good solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$file = "log.txt";
$list = $part = array();

foreach ( file($file) as $line ) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if (strpos($line, "|") === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $line = explode("|", $line) and $line = end($line);
    $list[] = substr($line, 0, 3) . " " . substr($line, 3);
}
var_dump($list);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string '192 ' (length=4)
  1 => string 'SAT  CLIMO' (length=10)
  2 => string ' 67 999999' (length=10)
  3 => string ' 70 ' (length=4)
  4 => string ' 66 ' (length=4)
  5 => string '  7 ' (length=4)
  6 => string ' 32 999999' (length=10)
  7 => string '       999' (length=10)
  8 => string ' ' (length=1)
  9 => string ' ' (length=1)
  10 => string '192 ' (length=4)
  11 => string 'SAT  CLIMO' (length=10)
  12 => string '999 999999' (length=10)
  13 => string '999 ' (length=4)
```

Comment: This isn't a solution to parsing fixed with data.  It's splitting on a delimiter.  Muck with the columns, it'll still work.  That's not the contract.  As suggested above specify the column start and length for each column and use substr().

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic PHP question answered in the O'Reilly PHP Cookbook.

[Parsing Fixed-Width Delimited Data](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch01_11.htm)

`substr` works fine. However, `unpack` is my favorite as it uses C function underneath and it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've use the substr() function to get data from specific fields:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

For example:

```
//Index:

012345678

192      
SAT CLIMO
 67999999
 70      
 66      
  7      
 32999999
      999
```

For the first column I'd have something like:

```
while($line = fgets($file)){

    $column1 = substr($line, 0, 3);
    $column2 = substr($line, 3, 6);
}

// for the line 32999999, you get:
// $column1 = 32
// $column2 = 999999
```

You can make those indexes constants and will have to play around with it to get it right at first with some character counting, but it will resolve the issue of numbers running together.

Answer (score -2):

I would use the [`fscanf`](http://www.php.net/fscanf) function here.